# What does the "device_" prefix mean in data_extraction_rules.xml file?

Tags: android, android-manifest

From the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup), we can use the `domain` property to specify the location of the resource in the `data_extraction_rules.xml` file.

Here is a screenshot from the doc:
[image: Screenshot of Android doc]

There are multiple values with the `device_` prefix. I have a couple of questions.

1. What is the exact meaning of the device-protected storage in this context?
2. When is it can be used?
3. Do I need to exclude it from the `data_extraction_rules.xml` file?